# how to get update from proximity sensor in background model in IOS

Tags: ios, background, sensors, proximity

I want to get the update from proximity sensor in background model in IOS  , but searched the whole internet no  answers
who can make it ?please contact me

Comment: Which proximity sensor?  The face detection sensor?  I don't believe you can get an update in the background as your app won't have control of the screen.

Comment: thank you Paul ,The proximity sensor for face /cover detection . in the scenario , I must use the sensor work in background model to detect the information from external

Comment: As I said this sensor is not covered by any of the iOS background modes

Comment: I opened this other question, to know if there is an alternative way to do that, without using the IR sensor    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31098799/how-to-get-update-from-proximity-sensor-in-background-model-in-ios